# SQL do not commit when hosted by server?

Tags: python, sql, flask, vercel

I made a website with flask which connect to a db file with sqlite3. When i run it locally it functions, but when I host it on vercel, the log shows no error but the db never commit and save any changes.

```
#example of a update
with sqlite3.connect(db) as connection:
    try:
        connection.execute("UPDATE Survey SET Responders = Survey.Responders+1 WHERE SurveyID = ?",(data["id"],))
        connection.commit()
        print("response added")
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

The database never save any changes, although i can select from the connection normally

Comment: It should be `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: @Barmar The execute method exists on connections also.

Comment: Must commit be on cursor? can you explain the difference between connection and cursor?

Comment: Vercel is on lambda, it is stateless. Your function probably does update the file, but the updated file is forgotten. It might last a bit longer between invocations if you keep it in /tmp bit that is not a real solution. For something quick I suggest DynamoDB instead.

Comment: @trognanders I am very new to this topic, do you mind explain more on this? Isn't the write done to a file? How can it be forgotten?

Comment: @WangTingan Basically imagine each request is handled by a different computer that is thrown away afterwards. You can change a local file, but the next request is handled by a different computer essentially with the base code.

Comment: @trognanders ohhhh i see, so if i host a mysql server somewhere else and query that instead of local db file, that will work right

Comment: @WangTingan Yeah that would work. Using AWS RDS can make it relatively painless. It is kind of annoying leaving the SQL server running directly on the internet though.

Comment: @WangTingan When using AWS Lambda directly there are things that can help like VPCs and connectors to provide a secure connection to the MySQL instance. Vercel may not allow you to use them. Let me know if you find anything useful!

Comment: @trognanders thx! for now I'm only using mysql connecter python to connect, but i host mysql server using other free services. This way I get to more control over it(I'm not sure...) The disadvantage is the added lag. Do you want to post ur answer as a solution? I feel like it explains the problem and the solution is relevant.

Comment: @trognanders the platform I used is freemysqldatabase.com It offers it's service for free, let you choose server location, 5MB, you can choose to renew the server every week to keep it running(takes only a few click) or upgrade to a paid plan

Comment: @WangTingan Your approach is very similar to using AWS RDS, which is a managed MySQL (or Postgres) server product you would connect to the same way.

Comment: @WangTingan The kind of messy part is that the MySQL server is open to the internet, which I consider to be a moderate security risk. Ideally, use TLS and verify the server certificate. Maybe even use a client certificate as well, although a good password and verified server cert are pretty good too!

Comment: @trognanders wow thx for the suggestions, i didn't start learning security and authentication yet, so i guess i will do more research